# How can I use the ngModel old value in a function if the value is asynchronous?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-ngmodel

I have an input (`dropdown`) where upon getting a new input, I want to check something about both the old and the new input. However, I have the data (old input) only in an async format.

```
<p-dropdown [options]="valueOptions" [ngModel]="storeValue$ | async"
 (ngModelChange)="checkChange($event, ???)" </p-dropwdown>
```

if the old value were not async, I could do the following :

```
<p-dropdown [options]="valueOptions" [ngModel]="storeValue"
 (ngModelChange)="checkChange($event, storeValue)" </p-dropwdown>
```

or if the store value were not nullable, I could do

```
<p-dropdown *ngIf="storeValue$ | async as val" [options]="valueOptions" [ngModel]="val"
 (ngModelChange)="checkChange($event, val)" </p-dropwdown>
```

Given that the value *is* nullable and that it is also async, how can I access it in the checkChange function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [tap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) operator to store the initial value. then you can compare with current value.

**component.ts**

```
storeValue$.pipe(tap(value=>this.initialValue = value));

checkChange(newValue){
    this.initialValue === newValue;
}
```